# OLEDB/ADO query speed in Javascript vs VBScript vs VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, vbscript, ado, hta

I have been building applications in VBA for quite some time but want to shift away from it for faster applications. We store all of our data in an access database on a network drive. Although, this itself could be a bottleneck I am curious of the following concept. Javascript in an HTA has been tested to be about 20 times faster than VBA when executing code and is atleast two times as fast executing compared to VBScript based on some websites. So my question is does this speed increase of using Javascript in an HTA also make opening a connection and querying a database with OLEDB/ADO faster compared to VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You are confused by C/S and B/S architecture. Javascript in an HTA cannot open database connections directly. It's pure client-side technology. Need to make calls to server-side API and the API connect the database.

Comment: Javascript allows you to create a ActiveX Data Object and OLEDB connection which can open a database connection locally in a file system or on a server. I am confident in that.

Comment: Sure for no. It's impossible for HTA to load local file system silently. You could imagine it's a disaster. Websites could steal your information. Nowadays, ActiveX died. HTA could only use browser storage/mini database there.

Comment: @GarryXiao Sorry, you're wrong with this, HTA has nothing to do with web. [HTA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ms536496(v=vs.85)#the-power-of-trust-htas-and-security) is a desktop app, it has full rights (almost) on user's machine, including the ability to connect directly to a database, to the filesystem and even to the registry.

Comment: Sorry, after my careful check, Yes, you are right. Confused by myself. It's fading out and I suggest not to use it.

Comment: Garry, you are right if a web browser could use something like an AJAX call on a file system then it would be incredibly scary but as Teemu noted these are for desktops. I find it hard to believe these will not be supported for the next few years so I think my question still stands and remains unanswered.

Comment: If you do concern the efficiency, my conclusion is that VBA is faster than HTA. VBA is compiled while HTA's javascript needs to be interpreted with the browser with a strict permission check and then both use oledb/ADO to connect the access database.